# I can't access my store after disabling all modules in Magento 1.9x

Tags: magento-1.9, database, configuration, admin-panel

I was trying to find an origin to an issue on my backend and I had the brilliant idea to disable all modules from the **advanced/advanced** tab in configurations.

Now my store is offline and cant access my backend.

I already tried to clear all info in **core_config_data** with this query

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 0 WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` LIKE '%modules_disable_output%';
```

I already Tried to delete all this info with delete instead Update
Cleaned the cache folder

Still get no result.
What can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rename the file below, and run the install process again, it'll enable again your modules and maintain all the information (don't worry when you see the install page).

```
 mv app/etc/local.xml app/etc/local.xmlOLD
```

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes. Thanks so much for the fast reply and the simplest solution. Everything worked like a charm.